# Understanding a remark about Kolmogorov Convergence Criterion

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The version of Kolmogorov Convergence Criterion I'm using is the following:

$\{X_n, n\geq 1\}$ is a sequence of independent r.v. . If $\sum^{\infty}_j Var(X_j)<\infty$, then $\sum^{\infty}_j (X_j-E(X_j))$ converges a.s.

In Resnick's «Probability Path», in page 213, there's the following remark about the Kolmogorov Convergence Criterion:
[image]

I don't understand how he can pass the limit to the interior of $Var$ or $E$. I thought of using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but $\sum^{\infty}|X_j-E(X_j)|$ may not be in $L_2$, even though the partial sums are... For the monotone convergence, I don't think I can use it, since we don't know if we have $X_j-E(X_j) >0$ or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is quite simple let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $X$ in $L_2$. Then $\mathbb{E} [ X_n ] \rightarrow \mathbb{E} [ X ] $ and $\mathbb{E} [X_n^2] \rightarrow \mathbb{E} [ X^2 ]$. Indeed, $X \in L_2 \subset L_1$ then $X \in L_1$ and 
\begin{align*}
\left|\mathbb{E} [ X_n ] - \mathbb{E} [ X ]\right| &= |\mathbb{E} [ X_n - X ]|\\
& \le \mathbb{E} [ |X_n - X| ] \\
& \le \mathbb{E} [|X_n - X|^2]^{\frac{1}{2}} \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}

This prove that $(\mathbb{E} [ X_n ])_{n}$ converges to $\mathbb{E} [ X ]$.

On the other hand

\begin{align*}
\left|\mathbb{E} [ X_n^2 ] - \mathbb{E} [ X^2 ]\right| &= |\mathbb{E} [ (X_n - X)^2] - 2\mathbb{E} [ X(X_n - X) ] + \mathbb{E} [ X^2 ] - \mathbb{E} [ X^2 ]|\\
& = |\mathbb{E} [ (X_n - X)^2] - 2\mathbb{E} [ X(X_n - X) ] | \\
& \le |\mathbb{E} [ (X_n - X)^2]| + 2|\mathbb{E} [ X(X_n - X) ]|\\
& \le |\mathbb{E} [ (X_n - X)^2]| + 2 |\mathbb{E} [ X^2]|^\frac{1}{2}|\mathbb{E} [ (X_n - X)^2]|^\frac{1}{2} \rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks Youem! ;)